# SciKit Gaussian Mixture Model ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn, gaussian

i'm trying to follow this [tutorial](https://github.com/jakevdp/ESAC-stats-2014/blob/master/notebooks/05.3-Density-GMM.ipynb) for GMM with Python SciKit. THe problem is that the original code does not work out of the box. It says there are problems with the shape of the input arrays and that GMM is now depreacated. I've tried to rewrite it as:

```
np.random.seed(2)
x = np.concatenate([np.random.normal(0, 2, 200),
                    np.random.normal(5, 5, 200),
                    np.random.normal(3, 0.5, 600)])
x = np.reshape(x, (-1, 1))

plt.hist(x, 80, normed=True)
plt.xlim(-10, 20)
clf = GaussianMixture(4, max_iter=500, random_state=3).fit(x)
xpdf = np.linspace(-10, 20, 1000)
xpdf = np.reshape(xpdf, (-1, 1))
density = np.exp(clf.score(xpdf))

plt.hist(x, 80, normed=True, alpha=0.5)
plt.plot(xpdf, density, '-r')
plt.xlim(-10, 20)
```

But still i get a `ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension`. As far as i can understand now the problem has been moved from the shape of arrays to the shape of `density` variable. But i'm not sure what is actually going on. Could anyone please shed some light on this? Thanks.

Comment: Seems like it is a known error according to the GitHub. The solutions they provide are to change the source code slightly or to not use a 1D array.

Comment: which command is throwing the error?

Comment: @PaulH the error now seems to be in the `plot` method, and caused by the shape of  the `density` variable. BUt i have no clue why, or what changes from the behavior shown in the example.

Comment: print out `density.shape` and `xpdf.shape`. Are they the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check the shape of `density` the problem will be much clearer:

```
>>> density.shape
()
```

The `score` method returns the log-likelihood of the *entire dataset* that it is passed, which is just a single scalar value. You want `score_samples`, which will provide the log likelihood of each individual point.

It's possible the API may have changed here since the tutorial was written -- I'm not sure.